# Configure the default search-directory for APK-files

Tags: xamarin, location, apk, uitest

I use the recommendation from MS to define a relative path to the APK for a UI Test. But upon running the Test, VisualStudio looks somewhere in my C: drive in Users instead of the solution folder for the APK. How can I explain VS to search within its solution dir and not within the users\appdata???

With an absolut path it work fine but I dont want to use absolut path in a project with many collaborators

The Code:

```
IApp app = ConfigureApp.Android.ApkFile("../../../_Test/App1/App1.Android/bin/Debug/com.companyname.app1.apk").StartApp();
```

The Error-Messsage:

```
ApkFile does not exist: C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\_Test\App1\App1.Android\bin\Debug\com.companyname.app1.apk
```